# Python Maths Issue

Tags: python

I am average at python and not even that at maths.

The equation y = 122.32e-0.31x can be used to calculate how much faster your web page load is compared to other. So a site that loads in 5 seconds is faster than 25% of websites.

Y is the percentage faster and x is the page load in seconds.

This data was found here - http://www.seomoz.org/blog/site-speed-are-you-fast-does-it-matter

To convert this in to python I have tried the following :

```
import math
# y = 122.32e-0.31x
y = (122.32*math.e)**(-0.31 * page_load_time)
```

Doesn't seem to be right. Can anyone correct the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import math
y = 122.32*math.exp(-0.31*page_load_time)
```

should do what you want

Comment: Thanks, MrDave. Appreciate your help. For a load time of 4.1 seconds that equation is returning me 0.000369500140113. Do I have to do more to interpret it as a percentage or is the equation off all together? I sourced it from the link above... but that just a quick google search.

Comment: From what I understand, it seems you are right. The R2 reported in the page you are refering to is so close to one that there is not much that can done further.

Comment: Thanks, all is working as required now. I have flagged this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The equation is `y = 122.32e`<sup>`-0.31x`</sup>

In python, it will be :

```
y = 122.32*math.e**(-0.31*x)
```

---

I did some time measurements :

```
>>> t = timeit.Timer('for i in l : e**i', setup = 'from math import e; l = range(10,50)')
>>> t.timeit()
23.76981210708618
>>> t2 = timeit.Timer('for i in l : exp(i)', setup = 'from math import exp; l = range(10,50)')
>>> t2.timeit()
13.754070043563843
>>> t.timeit()
23.382396936416626
>>> t2.timeit()
13.842521905899048
```

It appears that the implementations of both the methods are different and that `math.exp`, as mentioned by @MrDave, is faster than `math.e`

Comment: Seems we answered the question in the same time. BTW, what is the difference (if any) between math.e**x and math.exp ? it is not equivalent : this is what is get on a simple example :
>>> math.exp(2.0) - math.e**2
8.881784197001252e-16
The difference is not numerically significant, but still interesting